# Does SkyScanner API provide historical flight data?

Tags: api, web-scraping, get, analytics, skyscanner

I am trying out the Skyscanner API and testing the endpoint for browsing flights.

However, it seems to me that historical flight data are not available as I could only have a successful GET request when inputting future dates instead of past dates.

Can anyone confirm if SkyScanner API does not provide any historical data, and if so, is there any other possible way for me to get historical flight data? I am aiming to analyse trends in historical flight prices.

Thanks!